# How to make Android Volley request in a loop based on the response received in another JsonArray response

Tags: java, android

I'm making a JsonArray request using volley and then display the data in a recyclerview. What I'm trying to do here is to call another web service multiple times (in a loop) taking values of a particular attribute from the previous web service call.
For example: If I have a web service response like this:

```
[
{
    "RollNo": 7000026,
    "DOB": "18-11-21",
    "Mobile": null,
    "Name": "Richard John",
    "Class": "6",
    "Section": "A",
},
{
    "RollNo": "7000057",
    "DOB": "18-11-22",
    "Mobile": null,
    "Name": "Sam Jonas",
    "Class": "6",
    "Section": "A"
}
]
```

I then need to take the values of the `RollNo` and pass it to another web service which give me student pictures, in this case I have to call the Student Image web service twice. Then once all data and images are fetched, I have to show the data in the recycler view. I'm not able understand how to write that logic in my code. Appreciate any help.

current Java code for web service call and parsing of response:

```
public void STUDENT_DUE(){

    String HTTP_SERVER_URL= String.format("http://pastebin.com/);

    JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, HTTP_SERVER_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


                    STUDENT_DUE_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }){

    };


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsArrRequest);

}



public void STUDENT_DUE_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        StudentDataModel GetStudentDataModel = new StudentDataModel();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetStudentDataModel.setName(json.getString("RollNo"));

            GetStudentDataModel.setRank(json.getString("DOB"));

            GetStudentDataModel.setPerId(json.getString("Mobile"));

            GetStudentDataModel.setFromDuty(json.getString("Name"));

            GetStudentDataModel.setToDuty(json.getString("Class"));

            GetStudentDataModel.setHomeStation(json.getString("Section"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        StuDataAdapterClassList.add(GetStudentDataModel);



    }
    if (array.length() != 0) {

        recyclerViewAdapter = new StudentCardAdapter(StuDataAdapterClassList, this);
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

    }

}
```

Comment: if you are doing this i.e only image url from roll no... it will more easy to tell your back-end team to send image url with above response only.. so it reduce no. of web service call and reduce time consume also. because i dont think it is good idea to get only image url from roll no if you need more data then it is OK

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting, but at this stage, they can't help.

Comment: I see.. ok do it like first make call for student data now on STUDENT_DUE_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL method after GetStudentDataModel.setName(json.getString("RollNo")); line call webservice for get Image using GetStudentDataModel.getName and notify your recycle view on response of url API call and try to use GSON lib to parsing json so your code will also reduce

Answer (score 0):

With help of image loading library, you can inside RecyclerAdapter override  onBindViewHolder  to call second web service. To do that for example you can use Glide library to load image.
I am assuming you call second web service with get method and get each picture by RollNo.

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
String roleNumber = StudentData.get(position).GetName;
if (roleNumber  != null) {


 GlideApp.with(context)
.load("http://via.placeholder.com/roleNumber")
.override(100, 200) 
.fitCenter() // scale to fit entire image within ImageView
.into(ivImg);
   } else {
    // make sure Glide doesn't load anything into this view 

    Glide.clear(holder.imageView);
    // remove the placeholder (optional); read comments below
    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
  }
```

}